# How to implement Single Sign Out for Multiple Applications with Devise in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, single-sign-on, omniauth

There is a tutorial [here](http://codetheory.in/rails-devise-omniauth-sso/) on Single Sign On (SSO) for Multiple Applications with Devise, OmniAuth and Custom OAuth2 Implementation in Rails.

single Sign-on works but signing out only clears the session on current application as you can see from the destroy action below.

```
def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil

  flash[:notice] = 'You have successfully signed out!'
  redirect_to "#{CUSTOM_PROVIDER_URL}/users/sign_out"
end
```

the redirect_to method doesn't work because each app make a copy the session.

How can I extend this action to support single sign-out?